# apache - log4j could not find package after JAR upgrade

Tags: java, logging, jar, log4j

**Java Logger:**

For my java project, I upgraded (replaced) JAR files `log4j-api-2.1.jar` & `log4j-core-2.1.jar` with `log4j-core-2.13.3.jar` and it started showing error - `could not find package`

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

[image]

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.11.2/maven-artifacts.html

With reference of above links, I tried to change package name to. `import org.apache.logging.log4j.*` as follows, but `getLogger` found missing then.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.*;

public class LogManager {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogManager.class);
```

[image]

I looked around some (following) examples but couldn't find proper solution:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm

What can be proper resolution to this issue?